# [aspnetboilerplate]How to extend PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto to accept filters?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to pass filters to PagedAndSortedResultRequest.

```
public class PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto : PagedResultRequestDto, IPagedAndSortedResultRequest
{
    public virtual string Sorting { get; set; }
}
```

I want to pass a simple list of name-value pairs to this DTO in order to filter the result set.

The current implementation does not allow me to do it so I have to create a new class inheriting PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto. I am wondering if it is the right path to achieve my goal and there is any milestone to accommodate filter in the framework.

Thanks

Comment: Filter, or sort?

Comment: there's no milestone for this. You can inherit from PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto

Comment: Filter, @aaron.

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu Good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by @AlperEbicoglu, here goes my solution.
The solution requires three parts. Inherited request dto class, AppService passing the class, and overridden CreateFilteredQuery method inside of the AppService.

```
//Inherited Request DTO Class
[Serializable]
public class MyResultRequestDto : PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto
{
    public virtual int? ChannelId { get; set; }
}

//AppService 
public class MyAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Tenant, MyDto, int, MyResultRequestDto, CreateMyDto, MyDto>, IMyAppService
{

    //Overridden CreateFilteredQuery inside of MyAppService
    protected override IQueryable<MyEntity> CreateFilteredQuery(MyResultRequestDto input)
    {
        var query = Repository.GetAll();

        if (input.ChannelId.HasValue)
        {
            query = query.Where(t => t.ChannelId == input.ChannelId.Value);
        }
        return query;
    }
//...
}
```

Hope it helps anyone who needs it.